# how can I push new updates to my app that has sqlite changes in it?

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite

So I have an app running perfectly fine on the App Store , but whenever I push an update that has changes in the sqlite scheme, the app hangs.

When I change DB scheme on development environment , all what I have to do is delete the app from my iPhone ,re-install it again, then it works right ? how can I achieve the same goal in live version ?

is there something like DB number  - like when creating an android app - in which I have to change every time I want to update my DB scheme ?

Comment: This might be useful: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata. Have a look at the migration section

Comment: in here u need to use **ALTER** query for update the sqlite one db to another db, it will be work for updated the app without delete the existing one.

Comment: see this for help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448363/ios-keep-the-old-sqlite-database-while-updating-to-new-version

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik That totally helped ! Thanks